# How to join two unequal datasets with replacement? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to manipulate and merge two uneven datasets to one.

Text Sentiment - Dataset one

```
**text**   **sentiment**
angry      0
despair    0
fun        1
disappoint 0
joy        1
envy       0
```

Users - Dataset two

```
**Gender** **Age** **Salary** **sentiment**
F          24       23000     1
F          45       70000     0
M          32       29000     0
```

What I want

```
**text**   **sentiment** **Gender** **Age** **Salary**
angry      0             F          45       70000          
despair    0             M          32       29000
fun        1             F          24       23000    
disappoint 0             F          45       70000
joy        1             F          24       23000
envy       0             M          32       29000
```

Eventually what I want is to assign the sentiments to the user. But the lack of User data means that the user has to be duplicated to be assigned to the Text Sentiment. (first row of dataset one with sentiment of 0 with first row of dataset two with sentiment of 0 and so on, repeating users)

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='sentiment', how = 'left')
```